# How to auto redirect after authenticate using ember-simple-auth

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am using JWT (JSON Web Token) to authenticate user. I do include the `ApplicationRouteMixin` in `application.js` route and it supports to handle two events (success login and success logout) by default.

Now when I login with a user credential using code below,

```
  login(credential) {
    const authenticator = 'authenticator:jwt';
    const session = this.get('session');

    session.authenticate(authenticator, credential)
      .catch(() => {
        const errorMessage = "Wrong email or password. Please try again!";
        this.set('errorMessage', errorMessage);
      });
  },
```

The URL stay the same even the response is success and includes the valid JWT (see below).

```
{"jwt":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0ODg1NDIyMTcsInN1YiI6Mn0.Ma0ZtLWhoO1mb5cluGJZcKuHb-J2ZJdZOd3AFhVI258"}
```

When I refresh the page manually then the page get redirected.

However, when I am in the protected route after authentication, the auto redirect is working for `this.get('session').invalidate()` which kick me out of the protected route.

I know one walkaround is to add a `then` after `authenticate` method (see code below) to redirect the URL to the right one when there is a success response from the method; however, after browse so many examples I see no one does something like below.

```
    session.authenticate(authenticator, credential)
      .then(() => {
        this.transitionTo('browse');
      })
      .catch(() => {
        const errorMessage = "Wrong email or password. Please try again!";
        this.set('errorMessage', errorMessage);
      });
```

I am missing anything here? Why my route does not auto redirect after authentication?

Comment: Maybe you mixed in login route with `AuthenticatedRouteMixin`?!

Comment: You have an exception in `sessionAuthenticated` hook. Please check the error thrown there

Comment: I do not have any exception in my console.

Comment: Which version of ESA you use?

Comment: The latest version DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 1.2.0

Comment: Please check these conditions in https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/addon/mixins/application-route-mixin.js#L104. Of course one of those conditions wins before redirect to your config route

Comment: I had the same situation before, for a bad cookie

Comment: Thanks for the info. I may add a configure in ENV later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:jwt', username, password).then(
    () => this.transitionTo("index"),
    (err) => this.controller.set('error', err.error || err)
);
```

Comment: This is similar to what I have

Comment: If you do not specify where to redirect you upon successful authentication, how would your app know where to redirect you? You must add a 'then' or specify in your 'config' file the following:


  ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
    authenticationRoute: 'login',
    routeAfterAuthentication: 'index',
    routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated: 'about'
  };

Comment: config inside ENV is depecated

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just noticed the deprecation warning. I guess the only way that I have it working is by specifying a 'then'. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way on the internet!!! Hope you all enjoy it a lot!!! Here where I found: https://browntreelabs.com/redirection-in-ember-simple-auth/